# How to 'convert' a Static Access style project to IoC/DI style?

Tags: refactoring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, static-access

Are there any best approaches for refactoring a programming project that has previously been written with the static reference anti-pattern (the majority of classes refer at some point to  a static bean, where all of it's variables are public.

Half-way through a class, for instance you'll see something like:

`EvilClass.Variable = returnsABoolean()`.

Then in a different class, you'll see something like:

```
if(EvilClass.Variable == foo){
    doSomething();
}else{
    doSomethingDifferent();
}
```

Up until recently, I've been working with this pattern as I don't want to mix the styles and get things confused between the styles. But I want to slowly but surely 'fix' this project.

I'm the only dev on this, and I don't have the time to just sit down and refactor it (otherwise, I'd push for a full rewrite!).

Are there any best practices to be aware of when working with/fixing this kind of project/problem?

Comment: If you don't have the time to fix it, aren't sure how to approach fixing it, and it isn't broken and works, why do you need to 'fix' it? I mean is this something you want to do to teach yourself, or the project needs expanding or are you just fixing it for something to do?

Answer (score 4):

I would probably approach this with the following multi-step approach:

#### Phase 1:

1. If possible, isolate the static class.

   - In C# I would move the static class to its own assembly, or an isolated assembly, and make all its public members internal so that only a class in the same isolated assembly can use it.
2. Then, create a non-static class that exposes the static class.
3. Inject this non-static class into all other bits of code that required the static class.

#### Phase 2:

1. Make the non-static class a singleton (only temporarily) so that it throws an exception if instantiated more than once
2. Move all the static code into the non-static class.
3. Delete the static class

#### Phase 3:

1. Run your entire set of tests with this new setup (if you're lucky enough to have any)

   - Or, make a list of all code paths that use the new non-static class, and try to cover all of them with manual testing.
2. If you encounter singleton exceptions, then you're accidentally instantiating your non-static class more than once.  See why, and fix it
3. If you don't encounter any exceptions, you're safe.

#### Phase 4:

1. Refactor any code that uses your new non-static class so that it respects the Single Responsibility Principle.  This will be a lot of work, but should help prevent accidentally using the wrong instance of the non-static class won't happen.
2. Remove the Singleton pattern from the non-static class
3. Keep refactoring until all dependencies are injected everywhere :) (easier said!)